# Proving the continuity of the Dirichlet-like function using sequential charaterization.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Consider the following function: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x-1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & x \in \mathbb{Q}^{c} \end{cases}$$
When we prove that this function is continuous at $x=1$, we take two sequences say $x_r$ and $x_i$ of rationals and irrationals respectively such that $x_r \to 1$ and $x_i \to 1$ and then we show that $f(x_r) \to f(1)$ and $f(x_i) \to f(1)$ and we are done.

> How are we done if we haven't yet considered a sequence which converges to $1$ and has both rationals and irrationals (because for being continuous we have to check for all sequences which converge to $1$)?

Same is the case when we show that this function is nowhere else continuous; we take two cases:

1. A sequence of rationals converging to  an irrational(this yields that the function is not continuous at any irrational)
2. A sequence of irrationals converging to a rational( this yields that the function can only be continuous, if it at all is, at $x=1$)

In these cases yet again we haven't considered a sequence which contains both rationals and irrationals.

I know I am missing something here because I have seen this done this way at various places (my own instructor did it this way).

Comment: Just because you "haven't considered a sequence which contains both rationals and irrationals" doesn't mean there isn't one. I wouldn't use sequential continuity arguments here, but it seems you must. I would advise proving a lemma to the effect that if the sequential limits "via rationals" and "via irrationals" both exists and are the same, then the limit exists full stop.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If I try to consider such sequence say $x_{ri}$, how do I complete the proof? In that case, at rationals the sequence $f(x_{ri})$ takes values $x_{ri}-1$ and 0 at irrationals. How do I account for these $fluctuations$ and prove that still $f(x_{ri}) \to f(1)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I agree with you on that lemma. It is true since this has been done so. But how do I go about proving it?

Comment: $x_r$ and $x_i$ are poorly chosen notations for sequences. One could use $x_{r,n}$ and $x_{i,n}$ instead.

Comment: "When we prove that this function is continuous at $x=1$, we take two sequences say $x_r$ and $x_i$ of rationals and irrationals respectively such that $x_r \to 1$ and $x_i \to 1$ and then we show that $f(x_r) \to f(1)$ and $f(x_i) \to f(1)$ and we are done." Where is this assertion from?

Comment: @Jack well, I have seen it done at some places and now I know why it was done like that. It's because of the lemma that "Lord Shark the Unknown" is talking about in the first comment. On a sidenote, apologies for poorly chosen notations, I am a newbie.

Comment: Thanks. I think now this question becomes a duplicate of one of yours: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2452813/9464

Comment: @Jack not an immediate duplicate though. It has a life of its own. I asked it to get help on this one. The two of these together clarify most of the doubts. It's up to you, you might mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You only need the $\epsilon-\delta$ language. If $x=1$, then for any small $\epsilon>0$, we consider the interval $(1-\epsilon, 1)$. If $x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap (1-\epsilon, 1) $, then $|f(x)-f(1)|\leq \epsilon$ and if $x\in \mathbb{Q}^c$, then $|f(x)-f(1)|=0$. Therefore $f$ is continuous at $x=1$.

If we consider an arbitrary sequence $x_n\to 1$, then there for any $\epsilon$, there exits $n$ such that $|x_n-1|<1/n$, then we can follows the same argument as above and show that $|f(x_n)-f(0)|<1/n$, which implies the continuity at $x=1$.

For discontinuity, it is easy. If $x\in [0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$, we know that $f(x)=1-x$, we choose a irrational sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$. Then $x_n\to x$ but $\lim_{x_n\to x}f(x_n)=0\neq 1-x$.  If $x\in [0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}^c$, we know that $f(x)=0$, we choose a rational sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$. Then $x_n\to x$ but $\lim_{x_n\to x}f(x_n)=1-x\neq 0$.

Comment: Well, thanks on that. However, I was looking for an explanation through sequential charaterization on how to consider a sequence of both rationals and irrationals. $\epsilon - \delta$ definitely works, no doubts about that.

Comment: @MadhurPanwar I have updated it. Now, it  works for sequence.